# Magento 2 AWS auto scaling

Tags: magento2, aws, loadbalancing

I am not an expert in AWS. so please excuse me for this question. Our AWS EC2 instance host all the projacts of our client including a Magento 2 project, Wordpress projects etc. Each folders are pointed to different domains. Now my doubt is if I want to Auto scale this EC2 instance using Load Balancer what all things I should take care of? so that If I update the Magento code and ran static content deploy, the new code should affect in the scaled instances too.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

First of all this is not a good practice to have all websites in single instance, it could be cost saving but could be critical for management and security.

if you scale up your instance there won't be any issue ( i believe your instance is behind the load balancer already) and if you autocale that , it would be vertical scaling not horizontal scaling. Also it would be better to have separate DB instance. ( if it is not already )

Comment: what are you talking about? why he need vertical scaling???

Comment: i suggest this due to scenario and situation @Zammuuz is,  1 - hosting multiple projects and 2 - not AWS experience, having multiple instances need some expertise to handle infrastructure.

Comment: he needs to sort his infrastructure config first, as content sharing between servers is more important.